# Two different models embedding the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I've got two very similar collections. The only difference between both is that one (Item1) has more details than the other (Item2). 
Documents in both collections already have embedded "Detail" documents:

**Item1**:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5461c8f0426f727f16000000"),
    "n" : "Name 1",
    "detail" : {
        "d" : [ 
            "Frank Darabont"
        ],
        "a" : [ 
            "Tim Robbins", 
            "Morgan Freeman", 
            "Bob Gunton"
        ]
}
```

**Item2**:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5461c8f0426f727f16000000"),
    "n" : "Name 1",
    "detail" : {
        "d" : [ 
            "Frank Darabont"
        ]
}
```

I would like to let "detail" field be the same in both documents. I have both models Item1 and Item2 in the same app and they both have "Detail" embedded. The solutions I've seen for this is to call `:detail` different in both models but that doesn't work, as it looks in the Item(1|2) document for a subdocument that doesn't exist, returning `nil`. I have it like this right now:

```
class Item1
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_one :detail1, :class_name => "Detail"

  field :n
end

class Item2
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_one :detail2, :class_name => "Detail"

  field :n
end
```

But, in order to retrieve the "detail" subdocument, I would like to have something like:

```
class Item1
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_one :detail, as: :detail1, :class_name => "Detail"

  field :n
end

class Item2
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_one :detail, as: :detail2, :class_name => "Detail"

  field :n
end
```

This doesn't do what I expect. Is there a way to achieve what I want or changing Detail documents to have different names in each collection is the only solution?       :

Thanks.

Comment: Use the details as a stand alone model... Not embedded.. The embedded documents is only accessed through their parent... The cannot be shared among different parents

Comment: @artmees: The individual documents cannot be shared but the embedded class can be if you set it up as a polymorphic embedded document.

Comment: @muistooshort what i understood from the question is that he want's to share the document itself not the class... anyway kudos for your solution to share them if it works :D, and kudos for finding this in the documentation cause I've read it many times but never noticed this part :D

Comment: @artmees: I'm reading it as "same structure" but I could be wrong. We'll see when the OP gets back. But yeah, if it "same object" then there's no way to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#common):

> **Polymorphism**
>
> When a child embedded document can belong to more than one type of parent document, you can tell Mongoid to support this by adding the `as` option to the definition on the parents, and the `polymorphic` option on the child. On the child object, an additional field will be stored that indicates the type of the parent.

They even include an example (non-embedded parts left out for clarity):

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :photos, as: :photographic
end

class Photo
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :photographic, polymorphic: true
end
```

You should be able to set it up like this:

```
class Item1
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one :detail, as: :detailable
end
class Item2
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one :detail, as: :detailable
end
class Detail
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :detailable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Comment: This is just what I was asking. Thanks (and sorry for the delay) :-)